# Unable to start postgresql server

Tags: android, linux, postgresql

I can't start my etc/hosts file is alright.

```
Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server: main
Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf" exited with status 1
2021-11-29 12:33:13.333 UTC [17764] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 11.2.0-10) 11.2.0, 64-bit
2021-11-29 12:33:13.334 UTC [17764] LOG: could not create IPv6 socket for address "::1": Permission denied
2021-11-29 12:33:13.334 UTC [17764] LOG: could not create IPv4 socket for address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-11-29 12:33:13.334 UTC [17764] WARNING: could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-11-29 12:33:13.334 UTC [17764] FATAL: could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-11-29 12:33:13.336 UTC [17764] LOG: database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output. ... failed!
failed!
```

Comment: What is your setting for `port`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's default I didn't change anything

Comment: Then you have to ask your system administrator. By default, everyone is allowed to open sockets with a number over 1023.

Comment: When weird errors like that happen, the first thing I try is to disable SELinux.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm the system administrator and I'm running it in chroot . I won't be able to able to disable selinux as I'm running it in Android

Answer (score 0):

Founded it
If anyone finds themselves in this situation .
I added postgres to init group

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).